# PLEASE HELP with TACACS with AD auth (error: Expected 'service', but got 'servive')

Tags: tacacs

[How do you configure a TACACS+ tac_plus server on Ubuntu 16.04 that authenticates against Microsoft Active Directory?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/how-do-you-configure-a-tacacs-tac-plus-server-on-ubuntu-16-04-that-authenticate)

I ran all the `tac_plus` commands as per above but I cant seem to get answers for the following errors:

```
/usr/local/etc/tac_plus.cfg:49: Expected 'service', but got 'servive'
19500: /usr/local/etc/tac_plus.cfg:49: Expected 'service', but got 'servive'
19500: Detected fatal configuration error. Exiting.
```

Below is my config:

```
#!/usr/local/sbin/tac_plus
id = spawnd {
        listen = { port = 49 }
        listen = { port = 4949 }
        listen = { address = 0.0.0.0 port = 49 }
        spawn = {
                instances min = 1
                instances max = 10
        }
        background = yes
}

id = tac_plus {
        access log = /var/log/tac_plus/access/%Y/%m/access-%m-%d-%Y.txt
        accounting log = /var/log/tac_plus/accounting/%Y/%m/accounting-%m-%d-%Y.txt
        authentication log = /var/log/tac_plus/authentication/%Y/%m/authentication-%m-%d-%Y.txt

        mavis module = external {
                setenv LDAP_SERVER_TYPE = "microsoft"
                #If you are using Microsoft Global Catalog with secure LDAP (SSL)
                #setenv LDAP_HOSTS = "ldaps://192.168.0.97:3269"
                #If you are using Microsoft Global Catalog with regular LDAP (non-SSL)
                setenv LDAP_HOSTS = "192.168.0.54:3268"
                setenv LDAP_BASE = "DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxx"
                setenv LDAP_SCOPE = sub
                setenv LDAP_FILTER = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=%s))"
                setenv LDAP_USER = "tacacs@xxxxx.xxx"
                setenv LDAP_PASSWD = "xxxxxxxx"
                setenv UNLIMIT_AD_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP = 1
                setenv EXPAND_AD_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP = 0
                setenv AD_GROUP_PREFIX = ""
                setenv REQUIRE_TACACS_GROUP_PREFIX = 0
                exec = /usr/local/lib/mavis/mavis_tacplus_ldap.pl
        }

        login backend = mavis
        user backend = mavis
        pap backend = mavis

        host = world {
                #Allow any IPv4 device
                address = 0.0.0.0/0
                #address = ::/0
                prompt = "Enter Windows Crendetails.\n"
                key = "xxxxxxxxxx"
                }

                group = ops {

                            default servive = permit
                            login = PAM
                            service = shell {
                            default command = permit
                            default attribute = permit
                            set priv-lvl = 15
                        }
                }

                group = noc {
                        default service = deny
                                login = PAM
                                service = exec {
                                priv-lvl = 15
                                }
                                cmd = show {
                                permit .*
                                }
                                cmd = exit {
                                permit .*
                                }
                                cmd = quit {
                                permit .*
                                }
                                cmd = ping {
                                permit .*
                                }
                                cmd = traceroute {
                                permit .*
                                }
                                cmd = end {
                                permit .*
                        }
        }

                ### USER DEFINITION ###
                user = khensani.baloyi {
                member = ops
                }

    }
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

You misspelled the word *service*:

> default servi**v**e = permit